# Hover no funciona despues de haber usado js

Tags: javascript, css

Al cambiar el background de mi contenedor desde js deja de funcionar hover
al dar el primer click cambio de color y deja de funcionar hover

```
if(c1==1){
        document.getElementById(ide).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        icono.style.display='none';
        icono2.style.display='flex';
      }

//codigo css
.btn:hover{
background-color: #FFE9A4;
cursor: pointer;
display: flex;
```

}

Comment: Cuando haces un cambio de estilo directamente en el elemento, este tiene mayor [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) y se ignoran los estilos asignados por CSS. Deberías usar alguna clase adicional en lugar de modificar el estilo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando cambias el color de fondo con javascript lo haces inline, es decir, tu elemento tendrá el atributo "style" establecido, probablemente algo como `style="background-color: #ffffff"`.

El estilo inline siempre tiene prioridad al estilo definido en una hoja de estilo, a menos que se defina "!importante" en las reglas, lo que no es muy aconsejable.

Te recomiendo que añadas una nueva clase al elemento en lugar de cambiar directamente el color. Luego, con css, puedes lograr el comportamiento que deseas.

Sería algo así:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.classList.add('clicado')
});
```

```css
#btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}

#btn.clicado {
  background-color: teal;
}

#btn:hover,
#btn.clicado:hover {
  background-color: #FFE9A4;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Haga Clic</button>
```